# When decrypt data in HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, webserver

I know something about how it work HTTP and HTTPS but there is something stuck in my head.

How is decrypt encrypted data?
Where is this decrypting? Is on OSI layers or Web servers?

My web server have 2 domain and two domains have SSL themselves

- burak.com
- omer.com

This is my vHost Conf file for "burak.com";

```
vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.burak.com/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.burak.com/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  sslProtocol             30
}
```

- When client sending "hello" message, who decide to "Which SSL Certificate will using for this connection?", Litespeed or Operating System (OSI) ?
- If true answer is Litespeed, what is happening on "Presentation Layer" ?
- Is this decrypting doing on "Application Layer"?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. The wikipedia pages on Transport Layer Security and OSI layers should help you get answers. In short, in the TLS ClientHello record the client can specify, through an extension, which hosts it wants to connect to (which then make the webserver able to choose which certificate to present in its reply). TLS is most of the time handled by libraries, like OpenSSL or GnuTLS. The OS provides TCP sockets, libraries expose them as "TLS sockets" to applications.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Also, yes my question related to networks and web servers. Is this a problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic : this website is about programming questions. Your question is a generic introduction/tutorial on how TLS works and its applicability to HTTPS, so it is not on topic here.

Comment: (1) The TLS library. (2) Nothing happens in the presentation layer, because there isn't one, or any [tag:OSI] either. (3) Yes.